# Basic java script to get combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am just starting out with some java script in an asp.net mvc web site.

I current have a form which I am working on.

The first field which the user is prompted with is a combobox / select (in html)

here is the code for it:

```
<select name="select">

@foreach (var item in Model.networks)
 {
   <option value="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</option>
 }
</select>
```

Now my next field depends on the option which they chose from the combo box.

How can I populate the next field based on the option they chose in the combo box?

So when the user navigates to the page they will ave a combo box populated with all the options. Below that will be empty fields.  When the user selects a option in the combo box I want it to then populate the empty fields with the corresponding data from the option which was chosen.

How do I go about doing this?

Please give the newby answer as in the method in which it will be done. I am assuming that I will be using java script for it?

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot understand your question in detail, I hope I can help you.

**HTML**

If you have a select element that looks like this:

```
<select id=dropdown>
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

**Plain Javascript solution**

Running this code:

```
var element = document.getElementByID('dropdown');
var current = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Would make `current` be `2`. If what you actually want is `test2`, then do this:

```
var e = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Which would make `current` be `test2`

Answer (score 0):

Put the onChange="getSelectedValue" attribute of the select element and then use the following javascript.

```
<script>
function getSelectedValue(sel)
    {
        txtToFill.Text(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to react to a combo box value changing and display different content in your page.

If that is the case what you need to know is

- how to handle the change event in the select (drop down)
- populate empty fields

Here's how you can register and handle the change event in the dropdown:

```
$("select[name='select']").on("change", function(){
    $('#input1').val("What you want in the input goes here");
});
```

[**Here's a fiddle that demonstrates this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/c4Rt9/).